# I want to call a calculation method on an arrayList of Strings. Calling this method parallely for each element would be time saving. Is there a way?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, stream, hashmap, collectors

```
public HashMap<String, BigDecimal> calculateRevenueForAllMonths() {
    ArrayList<String> sMonths = new ArrayList<String>();
    //sMonths = list of 50 months

    HashMap<String, BigDecimal> monthlyRevenue = new HashMap<String, BigDecimal>();
    for(String m: sMonths)
      {
       monthlyVR.put(m, calculateRevenue(m));
      }
    }


public BigDecimal calculateRevenue(String mnth) {

  BigDecimal businessValue = new BigDecimal(0);

   //perform calculations
   //store revenue generated for the given month in a big decimal


return businessValue;
}
```

I want to parallelly calculate the revenue for each month and store it back to the hashmap to save time. It takes close to 5 mins to calculate revenue for each month, hence its taking hours for the above test to complete and return the expected calculations I need. Can I use streams to achieve this in any way? Pls help

Comment: `Map<String, BigDecimal> monthlyRevenue = sMonths.parallelStream() .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m, this::calculateRevenue));` Instead of `m -> m` you can also use `Function.identity()`.

Comment: I tried this but I get incorrect calculations. Should I be implementing additional logic to make it thread safe?

Comment: The code from Holger is correct. Try your old code with `Collections.shuffle(sMonths);` randomizing the order. And check you have no global variable of type SimpleDateFormat,. That one is not thread-safe.

Comment: Also use interfaces whereever possible: `List<String> sMonths = new ArrayList<>();` and `Map<String, BigDecimal> monthlyRevenue = new HashMap<>();` and `Map<String, BigDecimal> calculateRevenueForAllMonths()` ("programming against interfaces" which results in more expressive/general code.)

Comment: 'SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  Date date = null;
  try {
   date = format.parse(firstSnapshotDate);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy");
  String year = df.format(date);'
  
  I'm usingthe above method to calculate aggregate of all months' revenuew for a given year. Can I replace it with below code?
  
  LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse(firstSnapshotDate);
  
  Integer yr = dt.getYear();

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is not thread safe, but your code sample creates a new object each time, so this shouldn’t be the issue. On the other hand, using the `java.time` API is the better choice anyway. You don’t need to box the year into an `Integer` object, a plain `int` will do. You have to check everything within the `calculateRevenue` method. After all, it isn’t `static` which suggests that it depends on the state of `this`. Reading values which can not change during the operation is fine, but anything that could modify value requires thread safe constructs.